# NODE.JS how to show my css file which is inside the folder called CSS using node.js where my server.js and index.html is outside the folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

So, I'm new to `node js`. My folder looks like this

```
NODE //my main folder here

          ->CSS //this is a folder
          ->IMAGES //this is a folder
          ->node_modules //this is a folder where intalled npms are stored
          ->index.html
          ->server.js
```

I want my `style.css` which is inside the `CSS folder` to be shown in my `index.html` using `node.js`.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: can you provide some of your node code so we can understand how your system is working?

Comment: Most Node apps that I have seen separate the server files from the browser/client files. The client files would all exist under a folder called `public` or `client` or something like that. So, for example, you would have HTML files in `public`, CSS files in `public/css`, JS files in `public/js`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

In server.js include the CSS directory:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'CSS')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to make public folder in main directory . It should contain all the css,js,assets folder which is comman required.After that on your server file.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

For your case you can use:

```
app.use(express.static('CSS'))
```

and after that you can link css or any other public file directly as you do in normal html files.